# Read Files from Floder in Flash / Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'd like to make an image slider and mp3 player that would take files not from XML but directly form the folder and probably put them into an array.

After searching a while, I couldn't find specific answer on this question.

Is a thing like this achievable in Flash? and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is yes if you want to build a desktop app. Then you can access a folder via the air runtime. This is very easy:

```
var directory:File = File.documentsDirectory; 
var contents:Array = directory.getDirectoryListing();  
for (var i:uint = 0; i < contents.length; i++)  
{ 
     trace(contents[i].name, contents[i].size);  
}
```

If you want to create a web application. Then No.

Answer (score -1):

Flash, to my knowledge, doesn't have the ability to read directories -- Adobe AIR might be able to do this or you could use a server-side language to help you out [1]. I'm not sure about Flex, I've not used it.

[1] http://actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=88941&highlight=files+directory

Comment: A server side language will not be able to read a client side directory.

Comment: It can if the user is running the server on their computer and the files are hosted where the server can see them.

Comment: True; if the server has access to the local machine; either because the local machine is the server or because the server machine has directory access to the local machine; it is possible.  Neither are common situations in a production environment.

Comment: Given that the OP didn't give any specifics about their intended environment I think it's premature to draw any hard conclusions, though production is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: They also didn't specify where the files would be hosted (client or server).